# Reasons for disabled approve/reject buttons in suggested edit reviews

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Sometimes I see a suggested edit in the queue with the review buttons disabled like this:

[image]

What would be the reason for this? And why are these edits shown to me if I cannot review them? In general, I think any post I have already reviewed / cannot do anything about should be removed from my review queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be a few reasons for the buttons to be disabled:

- As you can see on the [reputation page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), you need at least **5000 reputation** points to approve or reject tag wikis, which also show up on the suggested edits.
- Besides tag wikis, your own edit suggestions you made will also show up in the queue. Obviously you can't approve or reject your own edit suggestions.
- You exceed the number of 30 votes a day
- You exceed the number of 5 votes on a specific user's edits a day

I guess the queue is just the same for every user and it isn't filtered on whether you can actually approve or reject it. The same goes for the flag page when you reach 10.000 reputation, you can see your own flags but basically they're just queued there, waiting for moderator attention.

Comment: To add, I know of two other cases: you exceed 30 votes a day or you exceed some number of votes on a specific user's edits a day. If there's work done to decide which buttons to disable, then surely it can't take much more to hide these posts?

Comment: some number = 5

Comment: @marcog added it to my answer

Comment: @waffles thanks for the clarification

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen suggested edits with disabled controls _enabled_ after a reload. Several times. Enough to wonder about it. :)

Comment: @sarnold I am struggling to find the code that disables these buttons, I wonder if this is a browser specific issue

Comment: @Waffles, it very well could be, but when I view the HTML source for controls that are disabled without any obvious reason why, they are very clearly labeled "disabled". But I've been away for a _long_ time, perhaps the problem is relegated to the dustbins of version control. :)