# Disabled Approve / Reject / Improve buttons

Tags: bug, user-interface, suggested-edits, review, 10k-tools

Why are the `Approve`, `Reject`, and `Improve` buttons in the **Suggested Edits** queue so often disabled?

I see disabled buttons like this every day:

> [image: Why are these buttons disabled?]

Some possible reasons where given in an answer to [Reasons for disabled approve/reject buttons in suggested edit reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83238/reasons-for-disabled-approve-reject-buttons-in-suggested-edit-reviews), but the answer given only documents a few causes. This is a bug -- the other post documents the legitimate reasons why those buttons are sometimes disabled.

The accepted answer gives several points:

> - As you can see on the reputation page, you need at least 5000
>     reputation points to approve or reject
>     tag wikis, which also show up on the
>     suggested edits.

<strike>16k</strike> 34k reputation. That's not it.

> - Besides tag wikis, your own edit suggestions you made will also show up
>     in the queue. Obviously you can't
>     approve or reject your own edit
>     suggestions.

My screencapture *is* a tag wiki, but it happens on questions and answers also. I have sufficient reputation to make edits without further review, so none are mine.

> - You exceed the number of 30 votes a day

Often, but I always wind up clicking `Approve` or `Reject` buttons three or four times before I finally notice the red text telling me that I've gone over my vote limit. I only get that red text when clicking on enabled buttons. Not all buttons will be disabled, just some.

> - You exceed the number of 5 votes on a specific user's edits a day

Often. Again, I frequently see the red text telling me about this after clicking on enabled buttons. Take a look at [this user's suggested edits page](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/54381): *Chathuranga Chandrasekara had 1 edit suggestions approved, and 0 edit suggestions rejected.*

With enough page refreshes, disabled buttons become enabled buttons. The *link directly to this edit* version of the suggested edit usually has the buttons enabled when they are broken in the main window:

> [image: broken buttons in the main view]

But, click on the little chain-icon to go to the page specifically for this edit:

> [image: working buttons of the link to the specific suggested edit]

I am tired of constantly opening the direct link to suggested edits so that I can use the `Accept`, `Reject`, and `Improve` buttons. I want them to always work on the Suggested Edits queue.

Comment: Rather than keep re-asking the same question, suggest edits to the original question or comment on the existing answers as to why they're unsatisfying.

Comment: @Mark, I commented on Apr 5 on the existing accepted answer; it received no replies. Because I couldn't give a rebuttal of every point in the space of a comment box in any reasonable legibility, and because the answer was completely inadequate to my question, I felt asking a new question was in-bounds. I _could_ edit the original question, but the original questioner appears to have been satisfied with their answer. (They _did_ accept an answer, after all.) _My_ original question was poorly asked and poorly researched; it doesn't seem worth reviving it.

Comment: So in other words, you didn't like/comprehend/understand/agree with the answer?  That's not reason enough to open a new question.  Offer a bounty on the existing question and put a custom message on the bounty indicating what you're looking for.  If you're admitting this is a dupe, then it's going to get shut down as one.  There are better ways to improve upon a topic than re-posting it.

Comment: Incidentally, [there is a workaround for this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113466/157556) -- if you load the page in a new tab the buttons are re-enabled.