# Please filter out edit reviews I can't vote on

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [disabled Approve / Reject / Improve buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93465/disabled-approve-reject-improve-buttons)
>   [UI annoyances in the suggested edit review on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow)
>   [Why are some buttons disabled in Suggested Edits and when I go to the post, they're clickable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101665/why-are-some-buttons-disabled-in-suggested-edits-and-when-i-go-to-the-post-they)

Got my 10k rep on Stack Overflow and spent some time voting on edit suggestions.

Pretty quickly I ran into the [disabled buttons issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93465/disabled-approve-reject-improve-buttons). It appears that I have voted too many times on a specific user's edits, perhaps? (there is no explanation as to why the buttons are disabled).

Could the edits I can't vote on be filter out please? Not only from the list (where they take up space completely unnecessarily, making votable edits harder to find), but also from the number in the top right.

Similarly, if I've already voted on something but it still needs more votes, I don't need the suggestion in the list anymore. It can go. There's no reason for it to remain in the list at all.

Comment: Strange...I have never faced such problem

Comment: @Lucifer see here: http://i.imgur.com/1s6Qp.png - that's three disabled, one enabled. Seems to be easily reproduceable for me; at one point they all cleared and now they're back again.

Comment: It's not you, it just happens occasionally. Reload the page and it works again.

Comment: Are the disabled buttons consistent when you reload the page (you may need to try several times and take notes due to the random selection)? I've never seen edits I couldn't review (and I've been doing about 400 a week (counting improves) for months). What browser are you using? I have had disabled buttons, seemingly at random (and not reproducible on page reload), with older (3.5 and 4.0 IIRC) versions of Firefox, but never with (recent) Chrome. (Cc @Matt: I think this isn't related to the UI annoyances but a JS bug.)

Comment: I can't find the link now, but as far as I remember there is no longer any limit on reviewing a specific user's edits (and I haven't run into the limit for months, so I'm pretty sure there isn't). The limit had not been implemented properly and was removed rather than fixed because the lack of a limit didn't lead to any abuse.

Comment: @Gilles yes, they are consistent on reloads. You're right about the limit; I eventually got to vote on several more edits by the same user whose edit had disabled buttons earlier on.